# How can you write tailMay in Haskell for Foldable, without using unsafe functions?

Tags: haskell

The signature should be:

```
tailMay :: Foldable f => f a -> Maybe (f a)
```

I was given this definition of `headMay`, which makes sense, and is (to me) rather clever:

```
headMay :: Foldable f => f a -> Maybe a
headMay = foldr (const . Just) Nothing
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to think of anything similar for `tailMay`, and [similar implementations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.13.0/docs/src/Data.Sequences.html#tailMay) seem to use magic or unsafe functions.

If this isn't possible, something that works for an `(Applicative t, Foldable t)` would also be fine for my purposes (which I gather would also imply `Traversable t`).

Comment: What would be the type of `tailMay`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann - I just realized I forgot to post that an added it while you added your comment!

Comment: Can't be done. Make a new class for it, or use more monomorphic functions that just work on the types you actually care about.

Comment: Suppose you have `data Three a = Three a a a` with `toList (Three x y z) = [x,y,z]`.  What should tailMay do, just return Nothing?

Comment: @DavidFletcher Thanks, a counter example is great for understanding this; hadn't considered fixed-length structures

Comment: You can make something with a similar type (but using `Alternative` rather than `Applicative`). But to make that something that looks like a tail requires a certain relationship among `foldMap`, `pure`, and `<|>`. Specifically, for any monoid `m`, any type `s`, and any function `f :: s -> m`, there exists a monoid morphism `p :: f s -> m` (from the monoid induced by `<|>` and `empty`) such that `f = p . pure`. That ensures that `f s` is the free monoid over `s` with `pure` as the injection, which is to say that it's basically a list.

Answer (score 4):

Tail only makes sense for list like structures, so it would be sensible to return a list, rather then the same container type `f`. Implementation is trivial and can be done in many ways, here is one.

```hs
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Data.Foldable (toList)

tailMay :: Foldable f => f a -> Maybe [a]
tailMay xs = guard (not (null xs)) >> Just (drop 1 (toList xs))
```

But, since it works for all list like structures, we could be cool and define it for all things that have is `IsList`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import GHC.Exts (IsList(Item, fromList))

tailMay :: (IsList l, Item l ~ a, Foldable f) => f a -> Maybe l
tailMay xs = guard (not (null xs)) >> Just (fromList (drop 1 (toList xs)))
```

**Edit**

A nice benefit of the above solution is that you can change types from the argument to the result. For example you can start with a `Vector` and result with a `Set`. But that also has a down side, you need to specify the resulting type yourself:

So running this will result in a compile error:

```hs
λ> tailMay [1 :: Int]
<interactive>:24:1-18: error:
    • Illegal equational constraint Item l ~ Int
      (Use GADTs or TypeFamilies to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall l. (IsList l, Item l ~ Int) => Maybe l
λ> tailMay [1 :: Int] :: Maybe [Int]
Just []
```

We can easily restrict resulting type, if above is really a problem or simply an undesired effect for us:

```hs
tailMay :: (IsList l, Item l ~ a, Foldable f, l ~ f a) => f a -> Maybe l
```

After that it works great:

```hs
λ> import qualified Data.Vector as V
λ> tailMay $ V.enumFromTo 'a' 'd'
Just "bcd"
λ> tailMay [1 :: Int]
Just []
λ> tailMay V.empty
Nothing
λ> tailMay []
Nothing
```

*Warning* - It all would be great, but unfortunately there is no guarantee that `fromList` will have a total implementation:

```
λ> import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE
λ> tailMay (5 NE.:| [] :: NE.NonEmpty Int)
Just *** Exception: NonEmpty.fromList: empty list
```

There is no general way to protect yourself from it, except by creating your own `IsList` like class and providing your own instances for all such data structures.

Comment: I wonder if the `fromList` could be wrapped in a `try` and return a Nothing in the event of an exception; not ideal but I may give that a try in a bit.

Comment: Ah, nevermind; I forgot that even though exceptions can be generated in pure code, they cannot be caught in pure code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a right answer to this question, as things currently stand, though I wanted to expand on @DanielWagner's comment, as it is probably the most performant option, while also being safe:

```
-- | Law: (fromJust (length <$> tailMay l)) == (length tailMay) - 1,
--   if tailMay returns Just
class TailMay l where
  tailMay :: l a -> Maybe (l a)

instance TailMay NonEmpty where
  tailMay = LNE.nonEmpty . LNE.tail

instance TailMay [] where
  tailMay = liftMay tail null -- <- from 'safe' package

-- from 'safe' package
liftMay :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Maybe b)
liftMay func test val = if test val then Nothing else Just $ func val
```

That said, ideally I'll get around to exploring @dfeuer's comment more as well.